# RestSharp Async API - Updating GUI

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am calling a Restful API using RestSharp in C# on opening the form, however on calling this the GUI opens and locks up.

Just wondering what I am doing wrong...

I have changed between Invoke and BeginInvoke, but no luck - the Debug output seems to hang somewhere between the first & second Invoke calls

```
public void show_members(String url, String api_key, String card_number)
{
    member_numbers.Clear();
    st_url = url;
    st_api_key = api_key;
    st_card_number = card_number;

    var client = new RestClient(url);

    var request = new RestRequest("pendingmembers?api_key={api_key}", Method.GET);
    request.AddUrlSegment("api_key", api_key);

    Debug.WriteLine(url + "pendingmembers?api_key=" + api_key);

    // async with deserialization
    var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<PendingMembers>(request, response =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(response.Data.status);
        if (response.Data.status == "OK")
        {
            //Company ID is Correct
            //Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)() => {cb_MemberList.Items.Clear();});
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    cb_MemberList.Items.Clear();
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                cb_MemberList.Items.Clear();
            }
            //Debug.WriteLine(response.Data.members);
            foreach(var member in response.Data.members)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(member.full_name);
                member_numbers.Add(member.member_id);
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(member.full_name);
                        cb_MemberList.Items.Add(member.full_name);
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(member.full_name);
                    cb_MemberList.Items.Add(member.full_name);
                }
            }
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue - was working perfectly as commenting out the whole Web API Call still caused the UI to hang.

On checking this was the `window.Show()` rather than `window.ShowDialog()` causing the issue...

Moral of the story, more sleep!